# How does the OSPFv2 and OSPFv3 instance learn the neighbor IP address?

Tags: ospf

For example, when I view the output of `show ospf neighbor detail` or `show ospf3 neighbor detail` in Junos, then I can see the IP address of the neighbor device interface. This field indicates the IP address of the interface to which this neighbor is directly connected. However, when I clear the OSPF or OSPFv3 adjacency and packet capture hello packets, then those hello packets do not contain the IP address. Does this mean that OSPFv2/OSPFv3 instance learn the neighbor IP address from IPv4/IPv6 header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that OSPFv2/OSPFv3 instance learn the neighbor IP address from IPv4/IPv6 header?

Yes